# Dreamweaver CC hangs when using Scheme Relative Javascript include URLs

Tags: javascript, adobe, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CC on Windows 8.1 as my main editor, when editing HTML files that include Javascript scheme relative urls Dreamweaver seems to hang for 15+ seconds after every edit and/or save.

It only happens when I use scheme relative urls on my Javascript includes (//).

For Example the following code would cause this hang to occur:

```
<script src="//googleapis.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Whereas if I replace it with the older version then no issues occur and these hangs simply vanish:

```
<script src="https://googleapis.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

What I think is happening is that Dreamweaver looks for the file but can't find it, Dreamweaver then hangs until a timeout occurs?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried to change the dynamic lookup in **General** -> **Preferences** but that has no effect and Dreamweaver seems to ignore it for these scheme relative urls?

[image]

Are there any known fixes for this?

Comment: Have you tried using the testing server for the document source?

Answer (score 0):

> If the browser is viewing that current page in through HTTPS, then
>   it’ll request that asset with the HTTPS protocol, otherwise it’ll
>   typically* request it with HTTP. This prevents that awful “This Page
>   Contains Both Secure and Non-Secure Items” error message in IE,
>   keeping all your asset requests within the same protocol.
>
> ***Of course, if you’re viewing the file locally, it’ll try to request the file with the file:// protocol.**

From [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/).

You have to run this on a server to make scheme use `https://` or `http://`.

Comment: Sure that's some kind of explanation of how scheme-relative URLs work, but that doesn't help his Dreamweaver problem does it?

Answer (score 0):

This sound more like platform issue, You can try to do this following steps first to figure out whats the problem and then solve it.

1. Edit your code only in code view (not even split)
2. [clear cache files for CC](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/494811)
3. try to remove an attribute from your javascript code example: `<script src="//googleapis.com/jquery.min.js"></script`> (I know this is not w3c validated, remember we are trying to figure out the problem first)

Try those steps by step and see if it fixes the issue, then move to next step if not, we need to know what part is interacting that causing that issue, i mention those steps above cause they are each concentrate with different part of CC application.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same thing recently - typically DW will freeze with a whiteout screen for 30 seconds upon opening some files for the first time. It's pretty random when it occurs.

Note that I'm using DW CS5 (v11) on Win 7.

Today it bugged me enough to break out [Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to try and work out what was going on. Sure enough I see this:

[image: Process monitor screencap]

You can see that DW tries to "open" the scheme-relative URL as if it was a network UNC path! Of course that doesn't work, but it takes 25 secs in this case to time out with a BAD NETWORK PATH error.

Note that there are no backslashes in my code! Here's the line from my CSS:

```
@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,400italic,700italic,700,500italic,400");
```

So basically this seems to be a bug in DW, going back to at least the version I'm using.

Others on the Adobe forums have reported similar: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1276130

I logged a bug report with Adobe here: http://www.adobe.com/products/wishform.html - If enough others do similar then they might eventually fix it! Sadly not for my version I suspect, and I have no intention of being forced into a subscription-only model to get the latest versions.

Having had a love-hate relationship with DW for the last 15 or so years, I keep saying to myself that I'm gonna write my own code-only HTML editor with FTP/file manager and source control support... one day!

Comment: Try phpstorm, themes take a little getting used to but it's a breeze to use and has all the ftp support etc.

Comment: Looks interesting thanks. Unfortunately I only use php for personal or smaller side projects... my biggest and main client is still on classic ASP!